# Sorting the values of a dictionary based on values of other dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this..

```
results = 
{'agunii2035': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii3007': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii2006': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii2003': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii3000': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003']}
```

and I have another dictionary with some score like this..

```
score =
{'agunii2035': [4, 4, 1, 3],
 'agunii3007': [4, 3, 3, 1],
 'agunii2006': [4, 3, 2, 2],
 'agunii2003': [1, 3, 2, 1],
 'agunii3000': [3, 1, 2, 1]}
```

I want to sort the values of "results" dictionary based on values of "score" dictionary.

For example,

For the key 'agunii2035', the score dictionary has values `[ 4,4,1,3]`. So, I want to sort the values of "results" dictionary for the same key as `['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000','agunii2003']` instead of  `['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000']` .

Comment: Have you tried using the function `argsort`? You can find it in the `numpy` package

Comment: how exactly [4,4,1,3] results in `['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000','agunii2003']`? Can you elaborate? you just swapped elements with index 2 and 3

Comment: @buran, I found it using some computations. I swapped only index 2 and 3 because the score for index 0 and 1 is 4 and that is highest (from the score dictionary) .

Comment: ok, get  it. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = {'agunii2035': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii3007': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii2006': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii2003': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000'],
 'agunii3000': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003']}

score = {'agunii2035': [4, 4, 1, 3],
 'agunii3007': [4, 3, 3, 1],
 'agunii2006': [4, 3, 2, 2],
 'agunii2003': [1, 3, 2, 1],
 'agunii3000': [3, 1, 2, 1]}

ordered_results = {key:[item for _, item in
                   sorted(zip(score.get(key), value), reverse=True)]
                   for key, value in results.items()}

print(ordered_results)
```

output

```
{'agunii2035': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000', 'agunii2003'],
'agunii3007': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
'agunii2006': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii3000', 'agunii2003'],
'agunii2003': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000', 'agunii2035'],
'agunii3000': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2003']}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the value of a dictionary lookup from score as the key for sorting results like this. This works because the default sort algorithm can use a list to sort by. It then uses a dictionary comprehension to build a new dictionary with the `key: values` from the sorted list.

```
results = {
    'agunii2035': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
    'agunii3007': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
    'agunii2006': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'],
    'agunii2003': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000'],
    'agunii3000': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003']
}

score = {
    'agunii2035': [4, 4, 1, 3],
    'agunii3007': [4, 3, 3, 1],
    'agunii2006': [4, 3, 2, 2],
    'agunii2003': [1, 3, 2, 1],
    'agunii3000': [3, 1, 2, 1]
}

sorted_results = {
    k: v
    for k, v
    in sorted(results.items(), key=lambda item: score[item[0]])
}

print(sorted_results)
# {'agunii2003': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii3000'], 'agunii3000': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003'], 'agunii2006': ['agunii2035', 'agunii3007', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'], 'agunii3007': ['agunii2035', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000'], 'agunii2035': ['agunii3007', 'agunii2006', 'agunii2003', 'agunii3000']}
```